# Nginx configuration issue: Node.js app works with location / but not with location /nodeapp

Tags: node.js, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location

I have a dockerized **nginx** server and a dockerized **nodejs** app.
When I run the nodejs app and expose its port `3000` on my `localhost`, it works *perfectly* when I access it at `localhost:3000`.
Now, I want to access my nodejs app through nginx.
I want nginx to act as a reverse proxy, so when I enter `localhost/nodeapp` in the browser, I get my nodejs app, and when I enter `localhost`, I get my standard HTML page served by nginx.

So, I wrote this nginx `default.conf` file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location /nodeapp {
        proxy_pass http://node-container:3000/; 
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't work. When I try to connect to `localhost/nodeapp`, I get a blank page and the browser console shows:

```
GET http://localhost/socket.io/socket.io.js 404 note found
Loading of the module at the address "http://localhost/src/code/graphic-app/GraphicApp.js" was blocked due to a prohibited MIME type ("text/html").
```

I thought the problem was with the nodejs app, but when I change `location /nodeapp { ... }` to `location / { ... }`, my nodejs app works perfectly at `localhost`.
My problem most likely stems from nginx transmitting the "location" path (`/nodeapp`) to nodejs, which then gets lost.
I tried `rewrite /nodeapp(.*)  /$1 break;`, but the problem persists.